# AWS autoscaling group - Getting event before removal from target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, autoscaling

I have an autoscaling group, which manages instances in a target group. Scale-down has the following sequence

1. Remove the instance from the target group.
2. Wait for draining to complete, so that instance is completely removed from the target group.
3. Terminate lifecycle hooks are triggered (which triggers lambda).
4. Instance is terminated.

Can we get an event on the first step itself, when draining starts?

We have a WebSocket application, which means clients have an open connection. So even keep drain time of 5 min, drains very few connections. Upon drain timeout, all connections are closed forcefully, causing all of them to reconnect with other instances at the same time, which causes sudden load and makes the whole app very slow. It also causes data consistency issues.

We have created a script that closes connections slowly from a given server to avoid the above glitch. For that, we need an even at the time of draining starts.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to fix your challenge if you can not find any other way.  You can disable terminating instances by auto calling group but when your Cloudwatch or any monitoring see that instance is not healthy, then you can call the Lambda function to close all the connections and then terminate the instance by Lambda itself.
That way you will be handled to this situation.  This is just a workaround if you can not find proper way.